# Any other alternatives to hide .plist files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, encryption

My app mainly uses .plist files for the majority of it's information. With jailbreaking so common and all the programs that make it so easy to view and edit the internal information files of apps, I want my hard work being unreadable, hidden, or encrypted in some kind of way. I know encryption is definitely possible and i seen the thread on here, however im not sure if there is only one way to do this or if encrypting is even the best and easiest option. Ive been searching for answers everywhere and just want to know all my options. Either way of hiding them or just making them unreadable in other way would do just fine. If someone tell me all my options to just make my .plist files secure and how difficult the processes are. Thanks alot.

Comment: impossible. at some point in time you need to decrypt to access the data by your app.

Comment: Ok well what part of this is impossible though? Im wondering suggestion for security purposes after project is complied. If your recommending i encrypt them then of course they would be getting decrypted within the app. Then the users wouldnt be able to read the files, only the app system, correct?

Comment: no. the key would be in the binary, even if you load it from a server - at some point an attacker can gwt full access. this is security by obscurity.

Comment: I dont get it, encrypted means encrypted. Whats the point of anybody encrypting in the first place then? And even if its possible by some hacker, im talking about just viewing from the installed .ipa folder after the app is on the device. Will a normal user be able to view the information inside the .plist? And what exactly does it look like when encrypted? Its still .plist just with a bunch of random mumbo jumbo within it? Im not experienced with this but this is what i would think.

Comment: If you just want to make it difficult to get to the data, your idea is fine. A normal user will just see random text - if a normal user would try to access the data anyway ...

Comment: Well what about a developer wanting to use my information that i spend time on for their own app. They probably know what to do then right? And what do you think about using Parse for the files. Apparently this mashes up the data so it isnt even a .plist and only parse.com server can read. But idk thats what a freelancer recommended. Id like to know what you think of Parse if you have used it.

Comment: haven't used it. but it will not be able to protect your data either. Remember: you encrypt but also include the key. there is no way to protect data from somebody with physical access to the device who should on the other hand be able to use the data

Comment: Well i had a freelancer and i was gonna pay them to set this up. They claim there is no plist files because they are stored on the parce server i guess and when first booted up the app downloads the data one time. And then i guess its in a whole new format. But yea i guess its common sense to know that if the files are being used then there HAS to be access to them somehow. This isnt a security bank type app by any means though, so for just hiding some basic information and not using the .plist that should be better than nothing. You seem to know more than me so idk your thoughts on this